# Get pixel color (Robot) when running full screen application

Tags: java, colors, pixel, awtrobot

I'm having this issue that I cannot find a solution for. 
I'm using `Robot.getPixelColor()` to get color of pixel at mouse pointer and it works great, however if I run a full screen application or game, it will display the color of the pixel in the background of the game (behind he game, in this case my desktop) instead of the color on the game.

Has anyone run in to similar issues?

The code is basically:

`Robot robot = new Robot();
Color currentColor = robot.getPixelColor((int)MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX(),(int)MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY());`

and then the color is placed as background of a jlabel.

Comment: Not having this problem. Are you using a JFrame or an applet?

Comment: This is often tricky, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723034/java-use-robot-while-running-fullscreen-app

Comment: Im using a jframe, and I also have multiple monitors (not sure if its the reason why)